# Import Large Shapefile to Postgres

Tags: postgis, shapefile, shp2pgsql

I'm trying to import a large dataset to Postgres, of about 600MB, that sits on a remote AWS server. But I get the following error

```
Not enough memory to allocate requested memory (nRecords=26923892).
Probably broken SHP file
```

I have a single core, 2GB ram machine. My question is, should I scale up the machine or if only I increase the memory allocation I get `shp2pgsql` to run smoothly even for big datasets (600MB and bigger)

Comment: What tool are you using to do this? have you tried shp2pgsql? What server type are you using?

Comment: I'm using `shp2pgsql` in a simple Azure Machine

Comment: 2Gb RAM isn't enough to run an operating system, much less a database.  Datasets aren't measured in Mb so much as rows. 27m rows for a point shapefile doesn't overrun the storage format, but for line/polygon it would.  Is it possible the error message is correct, and the shapefile is corrupt?

Comment: Scale up your machine (even for a short time) to get the data in. 2Gb is too low even for a desktop PC

Comment: Yeah, it seems that it's going to be the case. It has been working for small datasets, like 100mb, be I'll be importing bigger and bigger datasets

Comment: you can split the shapefiles into 6 100MB chunks and import them then append them in Postgres later. Not a lasting solution though.